# Python append rows in dataframe are flipped

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset imported from a CSV file to a dataframe in Python. I want to remove some specific rows from this dataframe and append them to an empty dataframe. So far I have tried to remove row 1 and 0 from the "big" dataframe called `df` and put these into `dff` using this code:

```
dff = pd.DataFrame() #Create empty dataframe

for x in range(0, 2):
    dff = dff.append(df.iloc[x]) #Append the first 2 rows from df to dff
    #How to remove appended rows from df?
```

This seems to work, however the columns are flipped, for e.g., `df` got order A, B, C, then `dff` will get the order C, B, A; other than that the data is correct. Also how do I remove a specific row from a dataframe?

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is just to remove the first two rows into another dataframe, you don't need to use a loop, just slice:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": [1,2,3,4,5,6], "col2": [11,22,33,44,55,66]})

dff = df.iloc[:2]
df = df.iloc[2:]
```

Will give you:

```
dff
Out[6]: 
   col1  col2
0     1    11
1     2    22

df
Out[8]: 
   col1  col2
2     3    33
3     4    44
4     5    55
5     6    66
```

If your list of desired rows is more complex than just the first two, per your example, a more generic method could be:

```
dff = df.iloc[[1,3,5]]  # Your list of row numbers
df = df.iloc[~df.index.isin(dff.index)]
```

This means that even if the index column isn't sequential integers, any rows that you used to populate `dff` will be removed from `df`.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it by doing:

```
dff = pd.DataFrame()
dff = df.iloc[:0]
```

This will copy the first row of df (the titles of the colums e.g. A,B,C) into dff, then append work as it should with any row and row e.g. 1150 can be appended and removed using:

```
dff = dff.append(df.iloc[1150])
df = df.drop(df.index[1150])
```

Comment: Please bear in mind that this will not work in a loop as `iloc` and `index` are not interchangeable. E.g. if your df is sequentially numbered, once you drop index 1150, `iloc[1151]` will point to `index[1152]`